# How do I convert this accumulate in a reduce (or some other parallel STL algorithm)?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl

I am developing a Barnes–Hut simulation in C++ for a course project. [Here](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut) you can find a detailed explanation of the algorithm.

I briefly explain the datatypes I will use later.

- A body is represented by the `Body` datatype, which is a struct containing a `Vector2f` representing the position, and a float for the mass).
- A node in the quadtree is represented by the `Node` datatype. Of course, the node struct contains some data, which can be: 1) Its four children, corresponding to its four subquadrants. This holds only the node is a fork in the tree.  2) Its body. This holds only when the node is a leaf of the tree. 3) Empty. This holds when the node does not contain any body. **Therefore, data is a `std::variant`.**

I wrote the recursive function that calculates the net force acting on a body. It takes in input a `Node` (at the first call, the quadtree's root) and the `Body` we want to query, and returns a `Vector2f` representing the net force acting on the body.
Of course, the function needs to visit the variant and dispatch to the correct lambda.

```
Vector2f compute_approximate_net_force_on_body(const Node& node,
                                               const Body& body) {
  const auto visit_empty = [](const Empty&) -> Vector2f { return {0, 0}; };

  const auto visit_body = [body](const Body& visited) -> Vector2f {
    return compute_gravitational_force(visited, body);
  };

  const auto visit_region = [&](const Subquadrants& subquadrants) -> Vector2f {
    float distance = (body.m_position - node.center_of_mass()).norm();
    if (node.length() / distance < OMEGA) {
      // Approximation
      return bh::compute_gravitational_force(
          {node.center_of_mass(), node.total_mass()}, body);
    } else {
      return std::accumulate(
          subquadrants.begin(), subquadrants.end(), Vector2f{0, 0},
          [body](const Vector2f& total, const std::shared_ptr<Node>& curr) {
            return (total + compute_approximate_net_force_on_body(*curr, body))
                .eval();
          });
    }
  };

  return std::visit(overloaded{visit_empty, visit_body, visit_region},
                    node.data());
}
```

The interesting part is the one with `accumulate`. Essentially, it invokes the algorithm recursively, with the same node and the four node's subquadrants, and accumulates the result into a `Vector2f`.

Since that the four calls are completely independent, I thought that I could make the computation parallel. Initially, I converted the `accumulate` into a `reduce`, but I later  discovered that this can't work because

1. [the types of the signature of the binary operation function must be identical](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) (mine are not);
2. The binary operation must be associative and commutative (mine is not).

I am looking for suggestions on how to parallelize the recursive calls, possibly using the STL library. If possible, the C++ standard must be C++17 or below. One approach that I have in mind is to use `std::async` and `std::future`, but it is less elegant than the accumulate-like one. Are there any other else?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Is that the right way to parallelize this? You have N bodies and for each you have to go through the quad-tree to compute the force on the body. So why not parallelize over the bodies instead deep down in the quad-tree?

Comment: You make a good point. I am already working on parallelizing over the bodies (and I am almost done with it), but for the sake of exercise I wanted to see if this further parallelization could produce a performance benefit: right now, I am employing `std::async`, but it does not feel very "idiomatic" (I might be wrong, though).

Comment: The larger work you can assign each core to complete the better. The overhead to distribute work will kill you otherwise.